# What does "WARNING: Input manager failed to load static dictionary for: nl_NL" mean?

Tags: iphone, localization, dictionary, static, simulator

I've been working on a dutch localization of a xib file. When I run my app in the simulator, I get the following message in the log console:

WARNING: Input manager failed to load static dictionary for: nl_NL

I've tried to reset the simulator, I've deleted the app, I removed the localization stuff and added it again, I've cleaned my project, but nothing seems to work. I keep getting this warning message.

My questions:
- can I ignore it?
- how can I get rid of this warning?

I've searched the web, but can't seem to find any answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens only in the simulator and doesn't cause any other issues, I wouldn't worry too much about it.  I just saw this warning for the first time today too.

Some follow-up questions may help:

Which SDK are you using?
Does it happen if you create a new Xcode project from a template?
Is your app still loading the localized nib correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I get the same message when I localise to Spanish (es_ES), but not when I localise to Japanese and to Simplified Chinese (or English for that matter).

I haven't been able to trace the cause or fix this. However in my case this is definitely not the localised xib files, but it arises when I call:

```
- (NSString *)language {    
    NSSet *supported_languages = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"en", @"es", @"ja",
                                @"zh-Hans", nil];
    NSUserDefaults *defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString *primary_language = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([supported_languages containsObject:primary_language]) { 
        return primary_language;
    }
    return @"en";
}
```

But this is only in the simulator.

On the device it works just fine as far as I can tell and I'm ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the 4.2 SDK. I've created the project from a template. It's still loading the localized nib correctly.

What I did find out was the following: it seems to happen only if I run the following code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions selector inside the AppDelegate.m file:

AboutViewController *controller = [[AboutViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:controller.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

If I comment out these lines, and replace it with another subview, it doesn't happen. The AboutViewController nib was the one which was localized. If I display the same view when the user clicks on an (i) information button, it just works and without the warning. It just gives me the warning when I do it from the AppDelegate.